# jQuery validate email as I type

Tags: jquery

The goal of the code below is, if the email address in the text field is valid, the submit button becomes active.

I've had this work using blur but it does not seem to work with keyboard events. 
Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    // default values
    var email = $("#newsletter_email");
    var button = $("#subscribe");
    var a = $(email).val();
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    // disable submit
    $(button).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(button).css("background-color","#CCC");

    $(email).keydown(function(event) {
        if(filter.test(a)){
            button.attr("disabled", "enable");
            button.css("background-color","#663399");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you make the event trigger on keyboard events, the rest of the method is incorrect.

You simply can't validate all legal e-mail addresses with that regular expression, and there's no sensible regular expression that can.

The only *reliable* way would be to perform an AJAX post of the data to your server, where you should perform an on-the-fly DNS lookup of the MX records (and if those don't exist, an A or AAAA record) for the domain portion.

For what it's worth, the reason it doesn't actually work for `.keydown()` is because the variable `a` is only being set *once* at the start of the outer function - you need to move the call to `$(email).val()` *inside* the `.keydown()` handler so that its value is fetched each time a key is pressed.

Comment: It's really not a concern, I just want to filter out empty field and random character submits.

Comment: Depends on your definition of sensible. I found one floating around on the interwebz. It took a while to find. It looks like a very lengthy paragraph. I'll share the link if I can ever find it again.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I've seen that one before, it's not remotely sensible.

Comment: @ok1ha there are plenty of "random" characters that are perfectly legal in e-mail addresses, particularly now that they're not all required to be ASCII.

Comment: @ok1ha This is entirely valid syntax for an email address: `"valid email addréss"@example.museum`

Comment: Thoughts on the jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: @ok1ha it won't help without proper server-side DNS validation of the current value